# Removing paths from sys.path

Tags: python

I have these files:

```
test.py
a/foo.py
b/foo.py
```

`a/foo.py` contains this:

```
x = 1
```

`b/foo.py` contains this:

```
y = 2
```

`test.py` contains this:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

here = Path(__file__).parent

sys.path.append(str(here / 'a'))
from foo import x
sys.path.remove(str(here / 'a'))
sys.path.append(str(here / 'b'))
from foo import y
```

This fails on the last line with:

```
$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    from foo import y
ImportError: cannot import name 'y' from 'foo' (a/foo.py)
```

Note that it's still trying to import from `a/foo.py` even though `a/` has been removed from `sys.path` and `b/` added in its place.

Is there a way to import both `a/foo:x` and `b/foo:y`?

Obviously the situation is not ideal but I'm trying to combine two libraries that happen to have a name collision.  Any suggestions for dealing with this are gratefully received.

I'm running python 3.8.6.  Python 2.7 produces very similar results (obviously adapted to avoid pathlib).

Comment: `pip` does not allow for name collision, so I am assuming these are local libraries. You already have them separated by namespaces; you can try importing them from the current directory and try `from a.foo import x` and `from b.foo import y`

Comment: I guess the problem is the cache https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules

Comment: @Flair - that works for the obviously simple case above.  But of course the practical case is more complex.  The libraries involved are not amenable to being namespaced in this way (they make assumptions about their own place relative to PYTHONPATH).  I think it should be possible to create some machinery using `importlib` to allow importing modules from sets of paths other than `sys.path` - I'll have a play and see what I can figure out.

Comment: If it is more complex than what you described, then I suggest `importlib`